# Why is Google Picker Hello World not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

i just changed the developerKey and clientId. upon testing, a popup showed to choose which google account should i use. after that, it showed a popup again for me to allow my application to access the drive. after clicking the allow button. nothing happened. popup closed. no message in console.

here is the link
https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to enable Google Picker API on your project:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=YOUR-PROJECT-NAME
2. Click on "**ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES**"
3. Search for "**Google Picker API**"
4. Click "**ENABLE**"

Now it should open the Google Picker correctly.

I hope it's clear!